# Error when running initialize firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

After running flutter build web, the application gives these errors on **Firebase.initializeApp**

> VM86:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module
> specifier 'Instance of 'TrustedScriptURL''
> at window.ff_trigger_firebase_core (:2:18)
>
> VM87:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module
> specifier 'Instance of 'TrustedScriptURL''
> at window.ff_trigger_firebase_app_check (:2:18)
>
> VM88:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module
> specifier 'Instance of 'TrustedScriptURL''
> at window.ff_trigger_firebase_remote_config (:2:18)
>
> VM89:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to resolve module
> specifier 'Instance of 'TrustedScriptURL''
> at window.ff_trigger_firebase_firestore (:2:18)

Through futter run everything works...